# If the poll phase is designed to wait for callbacks to be added then how does node know when to exit?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Taking a line from the [nodejs documentation](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/):

> If scripts have not been scheduled by setImmediate(), the event loop
>   will wait for callbacks to be added to the queue, then execute them
>   immediately.

My question is that how does nodejs know when to exit id the event loop is designed to wait for events if there are none.

For example:

```
console.log("Hello World");
```

the above just exits. There are no events scheduled but then according to the documentation Node should wait.